# How to dump full SQL of failing Django queryset?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying out a complex query on the `django shell`:

```
qs.annotate(rn=Window(expression=RowNumber(), order_by=F('date').desc(), partition_by=[F('name')]))
```

This is failing with:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "DESC"
LINE 1: ...ion"."storage_name", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  DESC) OVER...
```

I need to debug this. I would like to see the full SQL, before it is even sent to Postgres (since it is failing). How can I do this?

From a working queryset, I would simply do:

```
In [60]: qs = Consumption.objects.values('name')

In [61]: print(qs.query)
SELECT "consumption_consumption"."name" FROM "consumption_consumption"
```